# How to rotate CALayer and cover complete View on device rotation?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, calayer, screen-rotation

I have applied a gradient to a custom `UIView` by adding a `CAGradientLayer`. While this works fine there is small glitch when rotating the device and the view + layer with it. For a short moment the layer does not cover the complete view but the views / background is visible instead. How can this be avoided?

**Code:**

```
class BackgroundView: UIView {
    private let gradient : CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    func commonInit() {
        gradient.colors = [UIColor.white.cgColor, UIColor.black.cgColor]
        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
    }
    
    
    // Option 1: Adjust layer on sublayer layout
    override func layoutSublayers(of layer: CALayer) {
        super.layoutSublayers(of: layer)
        gradient.frame = self.bounds
    }
    
    // Option 2: Adjust layer on subview layout
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        gradient.frame = self.bounds
    }

    // Option 3: Adjust layer on trait collection change
    override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
        super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
        gradient.frame = self.bounds
    }
}
```

The result is exactly the same, no matter if `Option1` or `Option2` is jused, or both. In all cases the layer is correctly resized during rotation to its new, final size/bounds but not in the same way as the view itself. So the view and its background become visible for a short moment. How to avoid this?

The gradient should cover the whole view at all times.

I found several question on how to rotate a layer with its view. However, all answers provide on of the options I tried. I am doing something wrong or is this glitch normal?

**EDIT:** Updating the gradient bounds on a trait collection change has the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `layerClass` so the view's "base layer" is a `CAGradientLayer` instead of adding one as a sublayer.

Take a look at this:

```
class MyGradientView: UIView {
    
    // this allows us to use the "base" layer as a gradient layer
    //  instead of adding a sublayer
    lazy var gradLayer: CAGradientLayer = self.layer as! CAGradientLayer
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return CAGradientLayer.self
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        gradLayer.colors = [UIColor.white.cgColor, UIColor.black.cgColor]
        // other initial properties
    }
    
}
```